# Cleaning a moldy Ninja Blender so it is again safe for use?

Tags: cleaning, mold, blender

I have a ninja blender that was left in the fridge for too long and has a mold problem.

When I found it, I washed it with piping hot water heated by our gas water heater.   I've read some other places you have to use bleach and then let it dry out; but I want to know what to do for sure, so I'm asking the question here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bleach is safe to use, rinse well and air dry. I would be sure to use diluted bleach so as not to damage any rubber parts.
 You can also use vinegar but it will not remove stains as bleach does.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?  For instance how many parts bleach or vinegar?